Maven is unable to find the org.testng package in my project
Hye!

I have included testng dependency in my pom.xml
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
 <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
 <version>7.10.2</version>
 <scope>test</scope>


The TestNG plugin in available in the installed section in the eclipse marketplace.


Error in the Terminal after running "mvn clean compile":
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Smoke-TestNg: Compilation failure:
Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/salman.ali@ROLUSTECH.NET/eclipse-workspace/X2-CRUD-TestNg/src/main/java/Pages/Opportunities.java:[17,18] package org.testng does not exist
Detailed Screen Cast of the findings : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B9wjy7CotyiWCyCuPfVKJZFS59D5Y8Ma/view?usp=sharing

scope test means it'll be available under src/test, you are trying to use it under src/main? which doesn't really make very much sence, since testng is a testing framework, it shouldn't be used in your actual code

@Stultuske I have removed the  test from there. Then performed mvn clean compile.
This time "package org.testng does not exist" error was not encountered.
But still I am not able to run the project as a TestNg Project.

Again, TestNG is a TESTING framework, it should only be used under src/test, not under src/main. If you use something in a way it's not supposed to be used, you shouldn't expect it to work. take a look at this url: https://toolsqa.com/testng/testng-test/

X2_Crud_TestCases.java(The one which contains the individual test cases listed which I want to run) is already in the src/test/java in the tests package. You can see the video too. src/main/java includes the different modules. Each containing methods which will be called from X2_Crud_TestCases class.

yes, but you are using TestNG material also in src/main .

@Stultuske
Anyhow I have moved all those files to src/test/java
Now src/test/java has following items :
Pages : containing all those modules code
tests : containing basetest.java and X2_Crud_TestCases.java
utils : containing WebDriverManager.java
After this I ran : mvn clean compile, refreshed the project, restared eclipse.
Still X2_Crud_TestCases does not have the option to run its as TestNg project.

your current issue is: "I don't know how to use TestNG". That is to broad for a SO question, there are no doubt tons of examples and tutorials online. Your original problem was because you had an import of a TestNG class in src/main. That is resolved.

Change scope from 'test' to 'compile'
<scope>compile</scope>

Hope it works!

Thanks for the reply @Vamsi Krishna but the major problem still persists :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YcaDuKTgI2x3_LPqtjfYJj4HFdDoh9Ap/view?usp=sharing

@MuhammadSalmanAli - Since you are working with eclipse, please refer to the instructions explained in the official documentation site at https://testng.org/testng-eclipse/download to learn how to install TestNG eclipse plugin.
